# Chrome cutting off border & other visual glitches

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome

I suspect this has to do with some bugs in the browser, involving opacity, transitions and translations.

I wasn't able to reproduce the glitch in a code snippet, so I'll have to point you to the live site:

**[tzork.com](http://tzork.com)**

My **full source code** is here: [MightyPork/tzork](https://github.com/MightyPork/tzork), including the SCSS and Typescript that's compiled to CSS and JS. If you have time and can reproduce the bug, I'd be most grateful if you tried to find what's wrong. I've never seen anything quite like this before.

---

When you put mouse over the labels, they get a background and a border on one side, which should be 2px wide. Sometimes though, Chrome shows just one pixel. When I change the width to 1px, sometimes it shows no border at all (only near the corners).

[image: OK]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

You can clearly see how inconsistent it gets. My browser zoom is at 100%, so that is not the cause.

I'm not sure what's up, but it apparently depends on the current time = angle = position of the labels, and WINDOW SIZE.

I round the position to nearest pixel, so fractional position is not the cause.
I also tried rounding to odd / even pixel, that but didn't help either.

---

Another issue is that in Firefox, sometimes hovering the labels causes numbers on the clock face to **move / change letter spacing**. I don't get it, there's no connection at all.

In chrome sometimes there appear **weird tiling glitch** on the background image (notably when the dev tools panel is open).

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so the solution:

I added this all over the place, and the render glitches have disappeared.

```
-webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
```

I don't get it.